# WinRT Originate Error 0x40080201

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-async

I was writing some code and hit an error when doing heavy parallelism over an `IVectorView<StorageFile^>^>`. The Debug output was:

> First-chance exception at 0x76e86118 in tool.exe: 0x40080201:
>   WinRT originate error.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x76e86118 in
>   tool.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::FailureException
>   ^ at memory location 0x02daec60.

The code goes something like:

```cpp
task<vector<long long>> GetDatesTakenFromFiles(IVectorView<StorageFile^>^ filesInFolder)
{
    vector<task<long long>> datesTakenTasks;

    for each (auto file in filesInFolder)
    {
        datesTakenTasks.push_back(
            create_task(file->Properties->GetImagePropertiesAsync())
            .then([=](FileProperties::ImageProperties^ properties) {
                return properties->DateTaken.UniversalTime;
            })
        );
    }

    return when_all(begin(datesTakenTasks), end(datesTakenTasks));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I found out that referencing the `file` object from inside the inner lambda would make it work:

```cpp
task<vector<long long>> GetDatesTakenFromFiles(IVectorView<StorageFile^>^ filesInFolder)
{
    vector<task<long long>> datesTakenTasks;

    for each (auto file in filesInFolder)
    {
        datesTakenTasks.push_back(
            create_task(file->Properties->GetImagePropertiesAsync())
            .then([=](FileProperties::ImageProperties^ properties) {
                // I don't know why, but the file was being cleaned up. This prevents it.
                UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(file);
                return properties->DateTaken.UniversalTime;
            })
        );
    }

    return when_all(begin(datesTakenTasks), end(datesTakenTasks));
}
```

As a side note, I have to comment that this error only happened when iterating using `FolderDepth::Shallow`, but not `FolderDepth::Deep`.